# Want to play audio dynamically on user's click in angular from firebase

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I am making a dashboard where I want to play particular user audio which a user selects from table on play button.The recordings are stored in firebase storage. What happening is when I'm passing link manually its playing, but I want to play that audio only which user selects. 
What source should be passed or url format should be changed.

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Here's component.ts -

```
audio(){
     console.log("called");

    var audio = new Audio('https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/anaxeecallrecorr.appspot.com/o/audio%2Fuserrti%20Agrawal%2F6_9_2019%2Faud%2B9191769999%205%3A26%3A44%20PM?alt=media&token=0c25cf09-33b3-496b-a899-329b14082887'); 
//what src to be passed
        audio.play();
}
```

[image: This is webpage]

This is html file-

```
<td><button  (click) = "audio()" >Play</button></td>
            <td><button >Pause</button></td>
```

Comment: try to do a audio.load() before audio.play()

Comment: try pass URL as argument of your audio function.

Comment: Have you looked at the html5 <audio>? It can take an url in the src attribute, You could perhaps use it like <audio [src]="rowElement.url"> if you have the url in the row element. You might need to style the <audio> a little

Answer (score 1):

maybe try this way ... try to call a audio.load() before play() .. so somthing like:

```
    audio(){
         console.log("called");

        var audio = new Audio('https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/anaxeecallrecorder.appspot.com/o/audio%2FuserArti%20Agrawal%2F6_9_2019%2Faud%2B919176999149%205%3A26%3A44%20PM?alt=media&token=0c25cf09-33b3-496b-a899-329b14082887');

audio.load() //<--BEFORE
audio.play(); //<--AFTER


}
```

if you need to compose the url try to pass the id from the table like:

```
audio(id){
             console.log("called");

            var audio = new Audio(`https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/anaxeecallrecorder.appspot.com/o/audio${id}?alt=media&token=0c25cf09-33b3-496b-a899-329b14082887`);

    audio.load() //<--BEFORE
    audio.play(); //<--AFTER

}
```

Comment: How this will add url dynamically ?